# Request suggestions to improve my Apex class

Tags: apex

I am beginning to learn Salesforce Apex language and I have been picking up exercises to solve to practice what I am learning.
I have written a class to convert a nested list of integers (eg - {1,2,3} , {4,5,6} , {7,8,9} into a transposed list as {1,4,7} , {2,5,8} , {3,6,9}.

I would really appreciate any suggestions on the scope of improvement in this code as it will help me learn better.

I particularly think this logic is very raw and there should be a more concise way to evaluate this  -
if((l1.size() != l2.size()) || (l1.size() != l3.size()))

Class -

```
 public with sharing class Twodlist 
    {
        private List<Integer[]> originallist = new List<Integer[]>();
        private List<Integer[]> transposelist = new List<Integer[]>();
        private List<Integer> l1;
        private List<Integer> l2;
        private List<Integer> l3;  

    //Constructor taking input of the list of integers from user
    public Twodlist(List<Integer> ll1, List<Integer> ll2, List<Integer> ll3)
    {
        This.l1 = ll1;
        This.l2 = ll2;
        This.l3 = ll3;
    }
    
    //Method used to show the original list of numbers and the transposed version
    Public Void transpose()
    {
        originallist.add(l1);
        originallist.add(l2);
        originallist.add(l3);
        system.debug('Original List is -'+ originallist);
                
        if((l1.size() != l2.size()) || (l1.size() != l3.size()))
        {
            system.debug('Please make lists of same size');
        }
        else 
        {
            for(Integer i=0; i<l1.size(); i++)
            {
                Integer[] currenttlist = new Integer[]{l1[i],l2[i],l3[i]};
                transposelist.add(currenttlist);
            }
            system.debug('Transposed List is -' + transposelist);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Generally looks OK. Some trivial points: 1. validate the list sizes in the constructor and throw an exception if not all the same. 2. allow an arbitrary number of input lists by using a list of lists, direct to "originallist", which will allow you to apply transposition to the output of the transpose operation. This means you cannot use the static initialization of the "currentlist" that you currently do in transpose of course. 3. make transpose return a new instance of the Twodlist, not set a "transposelist" member. 4. stick with Salesforce's preferred case for keywords.

Comment: @PhilW Probably should have been an answer, you know.

Comment: @sfdcfox fair enough... done.

Comment: Apex...so verbose! We should learn APL as a second language. Transposition of list tuples in APL: {∪⌈\,⍉⍳≢¨⍵}⊃¨¨⊂ (from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/168561/tuples-by-sequentially-stepping-through-entries-in-list-of-lists))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally looks OK. Some trivial points:

1. Validate the list sizes in the constructor and throw an exception if not all the same.
2. Allow an arbitrary number of input lists by using a list of lists, direct to "originallist" (I'd rename this to "originalLists"), which will allow you to apply transposition to the output of the transpose operation. This means you cannot use the static initialization of the "currentlist" that you currently do in transpose of course.
3. Make transpose return a new instance of the Twodlist, not set a "transposelist" member.
4. Stick with Salesforce's preferred case for keywords.
5. Use mixed case to make names easier to read, likeThisExample for a variable and method names and LikeThisExample for classes.

Comment: Thank you so much for those suggestions Phil, these are really helpful points and you have given me an exciting piece of logic to try.. to allow an arbitrary number of inputs.